# PHP Framework that integrates with dojo

Tags: php, dojo

I am looking for the simplest php framework that comes integrated with dojo.  I do not need MVC or to learn a giant framework all over again.  Does anyone have suggestions or examples?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590/best-php-framework-w-ajax-support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"the simplest PHP framework" does not tell us at all what you're looking for.

To field a guess, however, I'd still say Zend is the best in most cases...It includes MVC capabilities, but does not *require* the use of an MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.comodojo.org can fit your needs... it's still in alpha, but it works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

zend framework http://www.zendframework.com/